# How can I get mySql to return Select JOIN with Count?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select, count, inner-join

I am having issues with the following stored procedure query.
I have 3 tables:

```
**table: prop_details**
prop_id | prop_title
     1  | sun
     2  | moon
     3  | star
     4  | mars

**table: prop_account**
prop_id | acnt_id
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
4       | 1

**table: prop_unit**
unit_id | prop_id
    1   | 1
    2   | 1
    3   | 1
    4   | 2
    5   | 2
    6   | 3
    7   | 3
    8   | 3
```

I am trying to gather the following output in the stored procedure:

```
prop_id     | prop_title    | acnt_id       | unit_count
        1   | sun           | 1             | 3
        2   | moon          | 1             | 2
        3   | star          | 1             | 3
        4   | mars          | 1             | 0
```

Here is the SP I have, but it is only returning 1 row:

```
PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN in_acntID int)
BEGIN
SELECT
  *, COUNT(unit_id) AS unitCount
FROM
  prop_units pu
RIGHT JOIN
  prop_details pd
ON
  pu.prop_id = pd.prop_id
RIGHT JOIN
  prop_account pa
ON pd.prop_id = pa.prop_id
WHERE
  pa.acnt_id = in_acntID;
END;
```

I am calling the sp like so: Call selPropertyByAcntID(@cntID) //@acntID = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select statement should look like this:

```
SELECT d.prop_id, d.prop_title, a.acnt_id
   , SUM(CASE
            WHEN u.prop_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS UnitCount
FROM #prop_details AS d
INNER JOIN #prop_account AS a ON d.prop_id = a.prop_id
LEFT JOIN #prop_unit AS u ON d.prop_id = u.prop_id
GROUP BY d.prop_id, d.prop_title, a.acnt_id
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for your response, but i am using mysql which i dont believe supports the full outer join.

Comment: your solution rocked it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN in_acntID int)
BEGIN
SELECT
  *, COUNT(unit_id) AS unitCount
FROM
  prop_units pu
RIGHT JOIN
  prop_details pd
ON
  pu.prop_id = pd.prop_id
RIGHT JOIN
  prop_account pa
ON pd.prop_id = pa.prop_id
WHERE
  pa.acnt_id = in_acntID
GROUP BY pu.prop_id;
END;
```